# Method query with multiple tables including ordering?

Tags: hibernate, join, named-query, spring-repositories

I'm not sure if I hit the boundaries of the method query with this task.
I have two tables, a `User` table and a `Password` table. A `User` may have multiple `Password`s (Where as the newest one is the current).

I would like to make a method query in my `User` repository to fetch a "current" `Password` for a user name.

In SQL it would look something like this

```
"Select FIRST(*) from Passwords INNERJOIN Users ON Users.id=Passwords.userId WHERE Users.username=%s ORDER BY Passwords.created DESC"
```

What I have tried as method query is `findFirstPasswordOrderByPasswords_CreatedByUsers_Username(String username)`

which gives me an exception:

`No property byUsers found for type long! Traversed path: UsersEntity.passwords.created.`

I don't know why it is still pointing to the `created` field. 
Is this too much for method queries? Or am I doing it simply wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define this method in Password repository as you are searching for password. In that repository this method will look like:

```
Passwords findFirstByUser_UsernameOrderByCreatedDesc(String username);
```

To implement this method, your Password entity class should have reference to Users table on User property(from the query)

Comment: Does this mean, that I'm limited to only get `UserEntities` from my `UserRepository`?

Comment: Yes, query methods in repositories are limited to entity, which repository is connected to. However, you can use method with custom @Query annotation containing query you want.